# How to handle further parameters in case of S3 classes?

Tags: r, class

Consider the following three versions which basically do the same 
(see reproducible example below):

1. `fun.class1 <- function(x, ...)`
2. `fun.class2 <- function(x)`
3. `fun.class3 <- function(x, y)`  [Idea: I would like to be specific in what 
   I need, so I thought I explicitly add the named arguments]

Question:

1. Why does 2. work? I didn't find anything in Hadley "Advanced R". I also
   looked for `??UseMethod` but if I don't miss anything, there's nothing 
   written about how the arguments like `y` in my case are handled?
2. The third version throws an error at `print(y)`. I feel like this makes sence (`y` is not known in `my_fun`). Is this explanation correct?
3. Without "`print(y)`", the function runs through and the output is `1 2` again. As `y = 1` cannot be handed over to `UseMethod`, y is treated as missing argument and the third variant `fun.class3` is in general a bad or wrong definition of a method?

**Reproducible example:**

```
fun.default <- function(x) {
  print("default")
  return(x)
}
fun.class1 <- function(x, ...) {
  print("class1 ellipsis")
  res <- x[y]
  return(res)
}
fun.class2 <- function(x) {
  print("class2 only x")
  res <- x[y]
  return(res)
}
fun.class3 <- function(x, y) {
  print("class3 x and y")
  # print(y) # Error in print(y) : argument "y" is missing, with no default 
  res <- x[y]
  print(res)
  return(res)
}
my_fun <- function(x) {
  res <- UseMethod("fun") 
  return(res)
}

x <- structure(c(1, 2), class = c("numeric", "class1"))
y <- 1
my_fun(x)
# [1] "class1 ellipsis"
# [1] 1

x <- structure(c(1, 2), class = c("numeric", "class2"))
y <- 1
my_fun(x)
# [1] "class2 only x"
# [1] 1

x <- structure(c(1, 2), class = c("numeric", "class3"))
y <- 1
my_fun(x) 
# [1] "class3 x and y"
# [1] 1 2
# [1] 1 2 # Why a second time? y = 1!
```

Maybe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58131498/5784831) is related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. Your second version works, because it finds `y` in the global environment. (Actually all of your examples find `y` there, since you never pass it to `my_fun`.
2. Yes, that's correct: The interface of `my_fun` expects that you pass an argument `y` that you don't pass. So it throws an error.
3. No, the third version is not bad or wrong. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58131498/correct-implementation-of-a-s3-method-when-should-i-use-ellipsis)